# When my app exist broadcast receiver not working? Android 6.0.1 Api23

Tags: android, android-studio

It's not working on Api23 ver6.0.1 below version are working fine.

My manifest code on below:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

can anyone help me..

Comment: Please check run time permissions

Comment: yes..ill check it manually and I will give the permission in setting also.its working on foreground and backround @Rasi

Comment: To help others who wish to help you, it might be a good idea to post the code for your broadcast receiver.

Comment: maybe its better to use service instead of broadcast receiver

Answer (score 0):

From API level 23 Android did some changes in granting permissions, now user have an option to revoke permission any time.

According to the docs -

> Requesting Permissions at Run Time
>
> System permissions are divided into two categories, normal and
> dangerous:
>
> 1. Normal permissions do not directly risk the user's privacy. If your
>    app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the
>    permission automatically.
> 2. Dangerous permissions can give the app
>    access to the user's confidential data. If your app lists a normal
>    permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission
>    automatically. If you list a dangerous permission, the user has to
>    explicitly give approval to your app.

Use [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) link to understand flow of requesting permissions.

Comment: What do you mean by after app exit?